# use word within span make class

Tags: jquery, class, tags

Hi I'm trying to add a class to to the project based on the first tag the project has.

So far this works:

```
$('.project_footer').ready(function() {
$('.project').addClass( $('.tag a').text());
});
```

However is finding every tag in every project_footer in the document and applying it as a class to every project. I just want the first one and apply it to that individual project.

Any advice?

EDIT:

```
<div class="project blue">
<p>content content content</p>
<div class="project_footer">
    <span class="tags"><a href="/projects/allblue">Blue</a></span>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want only the first `.tag` in each project?  Only the first `a` in each `.tag`?  For this to only run on the first `.project`?  Or only on the first `.project_footer`?  Your question needs some clarification as it's not clear which you want there to be only one of.  The answer will likely be to add `:first` to the right selector, but which selector depends upon understanding your question better.

Comment: Yea, we need to see the structure of your document. It's a little unclear.

Comment: got a solution for you, posting it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use both `parent` and `each` jQuery functions, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.project_footer').each(function() {
      $(this).parents('.project').addClass($(this).find('.tags a').text().toLowerCase());
  });
});
```

I just created a jsFiddle to show it working :) http://jsfiddle.net/MA9CV/1

**EDIT**

If you have more than one tag, change `find('.tags a')` to `find('.tags:first-child a')` like shown in this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MA9CV/2/

Comment: @uriah it depends the behavior you want, if you want the first one only, change to this `...find('.tags:first-child a')`

Comment: Bingo, should have read the other comments. `each` is not working for me its only selecting the very first project. Would be there a reason for this?

Comment: @uriah maybe your jquery version, which one are you using? or maybe a code mistake, is that your real code?

Comment: your jsfiddle works great, I just need to add `.ready` to make it work with the CMS I'm using. I'll look into the jquery version. Funny that its working, but only with the very first project and not the others. Thanks for your help @Nacho !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5906/discussion-between-uriah-and-nacho)

Answer (score 0):

I think we might need to see more of the HTML to see whats going on but possibly something in the lines of this `$('.project:first-child').addClass($('.tag a:first-child').text());` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you are selecting .page_footer? ready will fire after all the DOM elements has been loaded, and your code should probably look like this

```
$(function() { $('.project').addClass( $('.tag a').text()); });
```